# What is the time complexity for this algorithm which finds every prime number up to n

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, primes

Here's the algorithm in question, in pseudocode:

```
list.add(2)
for (i = 3 to n)
    isPrime=true
    for each (j in list)
        if ((i mod j) = 0)
            isPrime=false
            break
    if (isPrime)
        list.add(i)
return list
```

My TA today told me that this algorithm had a complexity of O(n^2), but I am quite sure that is incorrect, especially given that there are approximately n/ln(n) prime numbers up to any n, so the inner loop would not iterate more than n/ln(n) times on its last iteration if n itsself were prime. However I think it's actually lower than O(n^2/ln(n)) in reality, but I'm not sure how to determine what it actually is. For example, every even number only iterates the second loop twice.

Comment: Right now, it's just plain wrong. It's adding numbers to the list of primes when it finds they're composite. They're prime if and only if you check the currently known primes (up to sqrt(n)) and *none* of them divides the new candidate evenly. With that fixed, you're approximately correct -- the prime number theorem says 1/log(n) primes less than n, so you'll test against ~1/log(n) numbers, not N numbers in each iteration.

Comment: there's a point past where analyzing O() becomes pointless mostly; you've passed it. But then, this algorithm is wrong, so maybe what you *meant* by the algorithm would analyze differently.

Comment: Oops -- that should be N/log(N), not 1/Log(N). The problem is that he's *nearly* right -- log(N) grows so slowly that it makes *very* little difference to the overall complexity.

Comment: I fixed the algorithm. Also my intuition tells me the actual complexity will be in the neighborhood of O(x * sqrt(x))

Comment: You can easily omit the even numbers from the loop because there's no point in testing them; they're always composite (`for (i = 3 to n step 2)` saves some time, therefore).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Among `n` numbers you are checking for being prime there are approximately `n / ln(n)` actually prime numbers which demands all `i / ln(i)` already found prime numbers to be tried as divisors. Therefore, the complexity of your algorithm is `W(n^2 / ln(n)^2)` (`W` is big-omega) and `O(n^2 / ln(n)`. `n^2 / ln(n)^2` growths faster then `n * sqrt(n)`.

For reaching `O(n * sqrt(n))` time complexity you should use the following pseudocode:

```
list.add(2)
for (i = 3 to n)
    isPrime=true
    for each (j in list)
        if j > sqrt(i)
            break
        if ((i mod j) = 0)
            isPrime=false
            break
    if (isPrime)
        list.add(i)
return list
```

Answer (score 0):

The complexity is `O((n/log(n))**2)`.

You analyze it as follows.  There are two sets of numbers that you encounter, primes and composites.

You have `O(n/log(n))` primes, each of which you have to test against all smaller primes, for `O(n/log(n))` work per prime, for a total of `O((n/log(n))**2)` work.

You have `O(n - n/log(n)) = O(n)` composites, each of which has to be tested against at some subset of the primes below `sqrt(n)` for work bounded above by `O(sqrt(n))` so the total work is bounded above by `O(n sqrt(n))`.

Therefore the `O((n/log(n))**2)` term dominates.

Of course this isn't the answer your intuition was leading you towards.  You were trying to get intuition for what happens if you are smart and cut off the inner loop when the prime squared exceeds your target number, then how long would it take?  The answer turns out to be `O(n sqrt(n) / (log(n))**2)`.  The reason is that there are `O(sqrt(n)/log(sqrt(n)) = O(sqrt(n)/log(n))` primes below `sqrt(n)`, each of which needs to be tested for `O(n/log(n))` numbers (see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MertensTheorem.html for an indication of why this is so).

However at this point we've passed from the world of algorithms to the world of number theory. :D